# Howto call method extending IDictionary (reflection)?

Tags: c#, idictionary

I have extended IDictionary like this:

```
public static T ToClass<T>(this IDictionary<string, string> source) where T : class, new()
{
     T someObject = new T();

     foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> item in source)
     {
       someObject.GetType().GetProperty(item.Key).SetValue(someObject, item.Value, null);
     }

     return someObject;
}
```

And I'm having trouble using the method, tried it like this:

```
TestClass test = _rep.Test().ToClass<TestClass>;
```

And it says that it can't convert to non-delegate type.

What's the proper way of calling it?

/Lasse

- UPDATE *

Changed code to:

```
public static T ToClass<T>(this IDictionary<string, string> source) where T : class, new()
{
   Type type = typeof(T);
   T ret = new T();

   foreach (var keyValue in source)
   {
      type.GetProperty(keyValue.Key).SetValue(ret, keyValue.Value, null);
   }

   return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing the brackets on the end:

```
TestClass test = _rep.Test().ToClass<TestClass>();
```

---

The compiler thought you wanted to assign the method (delegate) to the variable.

---

Also, instead of `someObject.GetType()` you could use `typeof(T)`, I'd create a variable outside the loop and reuse it too.

Comment: Thanks alot George, merry xmas :)